# Flot: How do I grab the nearest plotted point to where the cursor is?

Tags: javascript, flot

I am trying to grab the nearest plotted point that the cursor is to. I

I found the `findNearbyItem` function in the `jquery.flot.js` source that seems to be able to do this, but when I trie calling it manually, I received the `ReferenceError: findNearbyItem is not defined` error.

This is the function I am referring to:

```
function findNearbyItem(mouseX, mouseY, seriesFilter) {
    var maxDistance = options.grid.mouseActiveRadius,
        smallestDistance = maxDistance * maxDistance + 1,
        item = null, foundPoint = false, i, j, ps;

    for (i = series.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (!seriesFilter(series[i]))
            continue;

        var s = series[i],
            axisx = s.xaxis,
            axisy = s.yaxis,
            points = s.datapoints.points,
            mx = axisx.c2p(mouseX), // precompute some stuff to make the loop faster
            my = axisy.c2p(mouseY),
            maxx = maxDistance / axisx.scale,
            maxy = maxDistance / axisy.scale;

        ps = s.datapoints.pointsize;
        // with inverse transforms, we can't use the maxx/maxy
        // optimization, sadly
        if (axisx.options.inverseTransform)
            maxx = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        if (axisy.options.inverseTransform)
            maxy = Number.MAX_VALUE;

        if (s.lines.show || s.points.show) {
            for (j = 0; j < points.length; j += ps) {
                var x = points[j], y = points[j + 1];
                if (x == null)
                    continue;

                // For points and lines, the cursor must be within a
                // certain distance to the data point
                if (x - mx > maxx || x - mx < -maxx ||
                    y - my > maxy || y - my < -maxy)
                    continue;

                // We have to calculate distances in pixels, not in
                // data units, because the scales of the axes may be different
                var dx = Math.abs(axisx.p2c(x) - mouseX),
                    dy = Math.abs(axisy.p2c(y) - mouseY),
                    dist = dx * dx + dy * dy; // we save the sqrt

                // use <= to ensure last point takes precedence
                // (last generally means on top of)
                if (dist < smallestDistance) {
                    smallestDistance = dist;
                    item = [i, j / ps];
                }
            }
        }

        if (s.bars.show && !item) { // no other point can be nearby
            var barLeft = s.bars.align == "left" ? 0 : -s.bars.barWidth/2,
                barRight = barLeft + s.bars.barWidth;

            for (j = 0; j < points.length; j += ps) {
                var x = points[j], y = points[j + 1], b = points[j + 2];
                if (x == null)
                    continue;

                // for a bar graph, the cursor must be inside the bar
                if (series[i].bars.horizontal ?
                    (mx <= Math.max(b, x) && mx >= Math.min(b, x) &&
                     my >= y + barLeft && my <= y + barRight) :
                    (mx >= x + barLeft && mx <= x + barRight &&
                     my >= Math.min(b, y) && my <= Math.max(b, y)))
                        item = [i, j / ps];
            }
        }
    }

    if (item) {
        i = item[0];
        j = item[1];
        ps = series[i].datapoints.pointsize;

        return { datapoint: series[i].datapoints.points.slice(j * ps, (j + 1) * ps),
                 dataIndex: j,
                 series: series[i],
                 seriesIndex: i };
    }

    return null;
}
```

If there are alternate ways of solving this problem, please let me know.

Comment: In case anyone else reads this and is mystified, OP is having an issue with [flot](https://code.google.com/p/flot/)

Comment: Added an identifier in the question, thanks.

Comment: You should also add some code that shows everyone what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's your use case for this?  If you increase the `mouseActiveRadius` option to something large flot will find the closest point to the cursor for you.

```
var options = {
    grid: { 
        hoverable: true, 
        mouseActiveRadius: 1000
    }
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/2054/).

**EDIT**

Yes, you can use the `plothover` event to retrieve the highlighted point.

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item){
        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
        console.log("x:" + x + ", " + "y:" + y);
    }
});
```

Updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/2055/).

Comment: That seems to be on the right path, is there any way to retrieve the coordinates of the point the cursor finds?

Comment: Oops, forgot to hand over bounty earlier.

Answer (score 2):

That's an internal function of flot, but you can easily recreate the same functionality yourself. All you need to do is iterate through the points in your data series and compare their location to your mouse pointer (Pythagoras should be able to help you here).

Comment: Could you elaborate on carrying out the comparison?

Comment: It's pretty much all there in the code you posted. Your can use the `c2p` method of the `axis` to convert your canvas coordinates to the plot coordinates and then compare with the X and Y values for each datapoint. The distance between the mouse and the plot point can be simply calculated with Pythagoras' theorem.

Answer (score 0):

As for the reason why you see: `ReferenceError: findNearbyItem is not defined` see [this](https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/33).
Applying this little patch by hand will make function public.